# How to do a simple search in Firefox DevTools' Inspector tab?

Tags: firefox, dom, search, firefox-developer-tools

I'm using the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Tools) and I'm using the *Inspector* tab, in which it displays the HTML tree.

When I use the `Search HTML` feature, it only searches tags. So suppose I have this:

`<div class="lol">textinsidediv</div>`

And when I search for 'div', it returns the `<div>` accordingly. However, if I search for 'textinside' it doesn't match the text inside the content despite the fact that it's starting right there.

**My question**: How can I search for any arbitrary string within this HTML tree?

(In contrary Firebug performs a simple text search just as expected.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not some really useless html tag search, it actually searches CSS selectors (same as what you use with css, querySelector in Javascript, or jQuery selector)

So you can search `#id`, go through all elements of a certain class by searching `.class`, you can even search for all elements with attribute including text, for example `[class*="o"]` should give all elements with letter o in class attribute. This is helpful for what designers/developers want to find - to find text, you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> within the page, then right click, inspect element.

Comment: still relatively useless (about 100x more useless) compared to just a firebug style simple text search which can do all of those above (and many others - including finding text) within split seconds

Comment: CSS searching is what I would think most developers want - the only really annoying thing for me at least is that it doesn't seem to search within frames on the page. What version of Firefox do you have? It may be affected by https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=881986

Comment: Wow, I had no idea this was how the search box worked. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, now i can search by id : `[id*=id_of_the_element]`

Answer (score 13):

The search in the *Inspector* panel of the Firefox DevTools allows to search for text content since Firefox 45 (see [bug 835896](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=835896)).

Btw. since Firebug 2.0 you're also able to search in the [*HTML* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel) [using CSS selectors](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2014/06/10/firebug-2-0/#searching-in-html-panel) (additionally to the plain text search).

Comment: Yes, and you can already try it out in [Firefox Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org/).

Comment: Released with Firefox 45. Just write the text into the search box, no special characters needed.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I've updated my response accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

A good idea is to Copy Inner HTML but even better is Edit As HTML. That brings up an in-place panel displaying the full text, and it can be searched with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to find next, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to find previous.

Comment: what keys to perform "find next" ?

Comment: Ctrl+G to find next, Ctrl+Shift+G to find previous. @林果皞

Comment: Yes, right-clicking the outermost element and doing "Edit As HTML" is the best workaround but it's insane that we need a workaround for this. You should just be able to use the search bar to search for text like you would in any other IDE or text editor

Answer (score 3):

Workaround: in the inspector, right-click the outermost  tag, then click 'Copy Inner HTML'. Paste in a word processor and search there.

Answer (score 0):

See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867820/how-to-do-a-simple-search-in-firefox-devtools-inspector-tab/34660122#34660122).

As an alternative to searching within dev tools...

- Right click on the page anywhere
- Select View Source

Within the source view you can easily perform a text search by doing a `ctrl/f` or `cmd/f` if on a mac.

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed as of FireFox 45...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_HTML#Searching

Comment: if it is fixed would you mind telling us how to do a text search?

Comment: Just use the search box, as you would search for a tag. No special characters needed. @Owyn

Comment: I have FF68, and if I type a text string that also happens to be an id or classname, it forces a search using the id or classname. I can't override it. For example, if I had <div id="test_1"></div><span>test_1</span> and searched for "test_1", it forces in "#test_1" and will only find the <div>.